# How to get current playback position for a live stream in Exoplayer

Tags: live-streaming, exoplayer

Is there anyway we can get the current playback position of a live stream from its start of streaming using exoplayer?

We have seen the post at https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2118#issuecomment-263536694 but for our stream, both period and window value is coming as 1. Is there anyway we can calculate the actual live position of the stream?

Here is a snapshot of the timeline that we are getting
[image]

Comment: Were you able to figure out a way to do this?

Comment: It is simple in case of hlsJS in web, but for exo, looks like we dont have interface to get data about at what point of the window the player has started playing the segment. I

Answer (score 1):

The start of streaming not presented in Exo classes.
You can know the start time (world clock) of the current window and add the current player position. this is your current position in world clock